# Jinja2 templating dhcp file without resetting file entirely

Tags: python, templates, ansible, jinja2

I'm relatively new to jinja2 templating and currently don't know how to solve the following issue:

There is some automation in place to deploy my OpenBSD router. Now I'd like to add another client to the dhcpd.conf file to provide fixed IPs on my network. How do I write a dhcpd.conf.j2 template, which doesn't simply need all parameters again that are defined in the dhcpd.file, but inject a new client configuration at a defined place?

```
option domain-name "something.info";
option domain-name-servers 10.10.10.1;
option ntp-servers 10.10.10.1;
server-name "pixie";
server-identifier 10.10.10.1;
next-server 10.10.10.1;

subnet 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option routers 10.10.10.1;
    range 10.10.10.10 10.10.10.254;

        host {{ hostname }} {
        hardware ethernet {{ mac_address }};
        fixed-address {{ ip_address }};
        option host-name "{{ hostname }}";
        filename "{{ filename }}";
    }
}
```

What do I need to add in order to render just the host block inside the existing dhcpd.conf file without changes to the existing configuration?

Comment: you are on correct path. You just have to make sure those variables set in your play book, and use `template` module so those variables will be passed to this template and transforms. May be examples like help youhttps://www.toptechskills.com/ansible-tutorials-courses/ansible-template-module-tutorial-examples/

Comment: You can either do a loop from a list of hosts, or "inject" information with the blockinfile module (but it may be more difficult to do)